# How could i find out the current zoom level on mapView(using MapKit)?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I was trying to do clustering map with this guide from [MapView with clusters: how to display multiple annotations on same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537450/mapview-with-clusters-how-to-display-multiple-annotations-on-same-view). 
While trying to do this, i encounter an issue related to the zoomLevel of mapView. Its said that the mapView doesn't have any zoomLevel() method. Could anyone explain me why its telling me that?

In addition, the current result that i get from it is that the map start clustering but not very smooth and sometimes the map gets lagging and shows more annotation than what it suppose to show.

I also need a guideline on how to use the FBAnnotationClusteringSwift library since i am quite confused of how to take this library into use.

Many thanks!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594827/how-to-find-current-zoom-level-of-mkmapview

Comment: Please check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806320/apply-zoom-level-condition-for-google-maps-ios/39807370#39807370

Comment: I got it. Thank you @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Thank you. i can get it now :D @Arun